# How do I use a SVG in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm using a Typescript app I created with create-react-app, with no other dependencies other than react and react-dom.

Using the  tag, how do I display an SVG?

I've checked that I have the right path because an adjacent PNG will render. Are SVGs different?

```
<img src={'../assets/triangle.svg'} alt=''/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to import the SVG in the top of the file, like this:

```
import FileSVG from "./file.svg";
```

and then use it as value for the src prop, like this:

```
<img src={FileSVG} />
```

Make sure to check if your path it is correct too!

Answer (score 1):

do not use direct path link in src...import it instead and later use that reference in src.

for example 
`import mySvg from "../asssets/triangle.svg"`

then: 
`<img src={mySvg} alt=""/>`